# C# Sidescroller starting advices

Tags: c#

since this is my very first time trying to make yet simple but useable sidescroller I'd like to ask some questions and hopefully gather ideas to make a good engine that can change the position of an Image in the form depending on X position of the drawn game character. I'd basically like to recreate just few seconds of a Mario game.

The starting Idea (correct me if it's wrong / poorly performance / whatever) would be to create a picture long in width and whit fixed height and upon the press of, for example, A or D keys, the drawn character moves till a certain X point, after that, character gets locked in place and if the key is still pressed, the background image starts moving.

But the problem there would be the fix for collisions, would be possible to check for the X position of the drawn background picture and set "collisions" accordingly for the character?

Other questions : why picturebox should be avoided at all costs and use the form itself instead ? Placing the greater part of the classes methods inside a timer_tick event is the wrong approach ? I read somewhere that the best way to do games of this kind would be relying on infinite loops in the forms main method, but I simply cannot even think how this could possibly works, taking in count all the times we may need to get out of the loop and do different code in different places.

Any other different ideas/approach and direct links to further explanations would be greatly liked

Edit : yes i'd like to improve with windows forms before moving to xna/unity

Comment: The question is somewhat borad; perhaps off-topic. Have you considered a tile-based representation of the level?

Comment: **Assumption:** You want to make a little game and its your first time working with moving graphics and you're working with WindowsForms. **Suggestion:** try using a more advanced framework such as MonoGame or XNA and working your way through introductory documentation and tutorials. Also WPF has a more advanced graphics platform for doing things like drawing and 3D, you may want to give that a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Assumption:** You want to make a little game and its your first time working with moving graphics and you're working with WindowsForms. **Suggestion:** try using a more advanced framework such as MonoGame or XNA and working your way through introductory documentation and tutorials. Also WPF has a more advanced graphics platform for doing things like drawing and 3D, you may want to give that a shot.

To expand on my comment a bit.

Windows Forms and GDI (the tech behind drawing) aren't meant for this kind of use. When GDI was created its purpose was essentially drawing lines and fonts on the screen. XNA is a really good framework for learning the basics up to professional design. Unfortunately the XNA framework is no longer supported by Microsoft and as such MonoGame is the recommended development route for managed .NET 3D and 2D game development.

The WPF provides [basic access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742562%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to Direct3D and Direct2D, and has 2D and 3D shapes and animations built into the framework and is what WPF is based on.

But you also have the choice, if need be, to create an XNA component and embed it in a Windows Form as demonstrated in these two tutorials.

[XNA in Windows Forms I](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1)

[XNA in Windows Forms II](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2)

Also using a Windows Forms Timer isn't recommended because they are unreliable. The .Net Framework provides a 'Server Timer' and a 'Threading timer' that can be used as well.

If you are really keen on using GDI for a game may I recommend reading about the basics of game programming (I think there are a few [XNA docs](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US) on the subject) that should guide you on things like the basic run time loop, getting input, and simple physics.

Comment: In the end I got to the conclusion that it's useless to overcomplicate things way easier to do with the proper softwares such as unity3d or monogame. Thanks again for your answer